# Breadth First Search two Strings

Tags: c++, string, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to create a depth first search algorithm when given two strings. I have built my graph but am having trouble with the breadth first search algorithm. I'm not exactly sure what I should do with my int a and int b that I get from my hash function.

For context....
Vertex node has a name ex. John, and a set of string, which are a lists of other names that John is friends with. I am given two names in main ex.  John and Mary, and I want to print out the paths that connect these two names. I only have code for BFS for integers, which is why I am getting slightly confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 struct vertex_node {
            string name;
            set <string> edges;
 };

 void Graph::paths(string start, string end)
```

{

```
bool visited[capacity];
    for(int i=0; i<capacity; i++){
        visited[i]=false;
    }

queue <string> q;

int a = hash_string(start) % capacity;
int b = hash_string(end) % capacity;

visited[a]=true;

q.push(start);
visited[a]=true;

while(!q.empty()){
    start = q.front();
    cout << start << " ";
    q.pop();

    for(int i=0;i < courses->get_capacity(); i++){
        for(std:: set<string> :: iterator j = list[]->edges.begin();
        j !=list[i]->edges.end(); j++){
        if(!visited[*j]){
             visited[*j] = true;
             q.push(*j);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, did you inspect your code line by line using the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

```
     for(std:: set<string> :: iterator j = list[i]->edges.begin();
         j !=list[i]->edges.end(); j++){
         if(!visited[a]){
             visited[a] = true;
             q.push(end);
         }
     }
```

Here you looped through `list[i]` by iterator `j`, but you never cared about `j`. You only confirmed many times that `start` is visited (by checking `!visited[a]`)

Comment: Would you mind editing my code to illustrate the mistake of mine you found? Thanks so much for your help timrau